# Tomcat include another xml file to web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

**Hello everyone,**

Since I have lots of servlet mappings in my web.xml I was wondering if I could actually store all the mappings to separate file and then include it to web.xml.

**servervlet-mapping.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>red</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Test.Red</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>red</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blue</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>blue</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Test.Blue</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>blue</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blue</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**web.xml**

```
<include file="servlet_mapping.xml"/>
```

This way it's possible to load xml files in struts.xml. (not sure if the same is possible in web.xml)

Is something like this possible? Or is there any other way to make it work?

(Apologies for my bad english)

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: You have them because the answer to you previous question is... well maybe technically correct but not the best solution to you problem.

Answer (score 7):

Servlet 3.0 introduced the concept of web fragments, which addresses your question about splitting the `web.xml` into multiple files.These fragments can contain a portion (or all) of the web deployment descriptor by including a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml`

```xml
<web-fragment metadata-complete="true" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd">
  <name>fragment1</name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>red</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Test.Red</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>red</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/blue</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>blue</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Test.Blue</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>blue</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/blue</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-fragment>
```

in web.xml

```xml
...
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyWelcomePage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyWelcomePage</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyWelcomePage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyWelcomePage/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <absolute-ordering>
         <name>fragment1</name>
    </absolute-ordering>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet version is below  3.0 then you cannot.

If you are using 3.0 there is a [possibility](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment)

> In JSR 315: Java Servlet 3.0 Specification, web-fragment.xml is introduced for pluggability of library jars which are packaged under WEB-INF/lib. The content of web.xml and web-fragment.xml are almost the same. One can define servlets, filters and listeners there. One can also specify metadata-complete=true in a given web-fragment.xml. In the latter case, the annotation processing of classes in that jar would be skipped. With web-fragment.xml, library jars can be self-contained and provide web related metadata information.

But having two `XML` may confuse you.Just try this.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

From @BalusC comment below:

***DO NOT DO THIS! You're basically utilizing a Tomcat-specific security exploit which is fixed in newer Tomcat versions and not necessarily present in different servers. In other words, the webapp with such a web.xml is unportable. Related issue report: bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1069911***

Leaving the answer here so that people who read this know that it is wrong.

**Original Answer**

You can try below approach (based on the concept of external XML entities):

```
web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" [
 <!ENTITY textreplacements SYSTEM "textreplacements.xml">
]>
<web-app>
<filter>
    <filter-name>TextReplaceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>TextReplaceFilter</filter-class>
    &textreplacements;
</filter>
```

```
textreplacements.xml

<init-param>
  <param-name>whatever</param-name>
  <param-value>whenever</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! You're basically utilizing a Tomcat-specific security exploit which is fixed in newer Tomcat versions and not necessarily present in different servers. In other words, the webapp with such a web.xml is unportable. Related issue report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1069911