# Map servlet programmatically instead of using web.xml or annotations

Tags: servlets, mapping, programmatic-config

How can I implement this mapping programmatically without web.xml or annotations? The mission is not to use any framework like spring or something else.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If you don't have a framework, there's no such thing as a "view resolver", since it's the frameworks that provide such a feature.

Comment: You could create a servlet that handles the mapping and invokes other servlets. That is what spring does. The servlet is the place where the container interfaces with the application so practically you will need at least one servlet.

Comment: @Marta, I understand you are trying to learn. But, what exactly are you trying to learn? If you are learning Servlets, then you should learn about the servlet-mapping in web.xml and to do the mapping using Annotations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Servlet 3.0 you can use [`ServletContext#addServlet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) for this.

```
servletContext.addServlet("hello", test.HelloServlet.class);
```

Depending on what you're developing, there are two hooks where you can run this code.

1. If you're developing a publicly reusable modular web fragment JAR file such as existing frameworks like JSF and Spring MVC, then use a [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html).

   ```
   public class YourFrameworkInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

       @Override
       public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
           servletContext.addServlet("hello", test.HelloServlet.class);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Or, if you're using it as an internally integrated part of your WAR application, then use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

   ```
   @WebListener
   public class YourFrameworkInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

       @Override
       public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
           event.getServletContext().addServlet("hello", test.HelloServlet.class);
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

You only need to make sure that your `web.xml` is compatible with Servlet 3.0 or newer (and thus not Servlet 2.5 or older), otherwise the servletcontainer will run in fallback modus complying the declared version and you will lose all Servlet 3.0 features.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
>
    <!-- Config here -->
</web-app>
```

#### See also:

- [ServletContainerInitializer vs ServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776599/servletcontainerinitializer-vs-servletcontextlistener)
- [@WebServlet annotation with Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7)
- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)
- [Splitting up shared code and web.xml from WAR project to common JAR project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046979/splitting-up-shared-code-and-web-xml-from-war-project-to-common-jar-project/)

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: What about the mapping?

Comment: To specify mapping, use `servletContext.addServlet("SomeName", SomeClass.class).addMapping("/someUrlPattern");`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use annotations to achieve this using code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello");
    }
}
```

You can read about annotations [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html)

Comment: I believe this a the best method, but still is there any way to map without annotation and without using .xml descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tomcat 7 or above you can done this by annotation

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
```

Comment: Nice thank you, option one which I will try. But as I'm just learning I would really like to go the hard way and do the mapping without annotations. So if there is any way please drop a hint.